# Enabling TurboModule and Fabric in React Native 0.68 leads to lot of error

Tags: ios, react-native, objective-c++

I am using `React Native 0.68` and trying to use `TurboModules` and `Fabric`

This is my `AppDelegate.mm` file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h>

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
#import <React/RCTDataRequestHandler.h>
#import <React/RCTHTTPRequestHandler.h>
#import <React/RCTFileRequestHandler.h>
#import <React/RCTNetworking.h>
#import <React/RCTImageLoader.h>
#import <React/RCTGIFImageDecoder.h>
#import <React/RCTLocalAssetImageLoader.h>

#import <React/CoreModulesPlugins.h>
#import <React/RCTCxxBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <React/RCTFabricSurfaceHostingProxyRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenter.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter.h>
#import <ReactCommon/RCTTurboModuleManager.h>

#import <react/config/ReactNativeConfig.h>

@interface AppDelegate () <RCTCxxBridgeDelegate, RCTTurboModuleManagerDelegate> {
  RCTTurboModuleManager *_turboModuleManager;
  RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter *_bridgeAdapter;
  std::shared_ptr<const facebook::react::ReactNativeConfig> _reactNativeConfig;
  facebook::react::ContextContainer::Shared _contextContainer;
}
@end
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application);
  // RCTEnableTurboModule(YES);
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
  _contextContainer = std::make_shared<facebook::react::ContextContainer const>();
  _reactNativeConfig = std::make_shared<facebook::react::EmptyReactNativeConfig const>();
  _contextContainer->insert("ReactNativeConfig", _reactNativeConfig);
  _bridgeAdapter = [[RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter alloc] initWithBridge:bridge contextContainer:_contextContainer];
  bridge.surfacePresenter = _bridgeAdapter.surfacePresenter;
#endif

  UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"DummyProject2", nil);

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
    rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED

#pragma mark - RCTCxxBridgeDelegate

- (std::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory>)jsExecutorFactoryForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  if (RCTTurboModuleEnabled()) {
    _turboModuleManager =
        [[RCTTurboModuleManager alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                             delegate:self
                                            jsInvoker:bridge.jsCallInvoker];

    // Necessary to allow NativeModules to lookup TurboModules
    [bridge setRCTTurboModuleRegistry:_turboModuleManager];

    if (!RCTTurboModuleEagerInitEnabled()) {
      /**
       * Instantiating DevMenu has the side-effect of registering
       * shortcuts for CMD + d, CMD + i,  and CMD + n via RCTDevMenu.
       * Therefore, when TurboModules are enabled, we must manually create this
       * NativeModule.
       */
       [_turboModuleManager moduleForName:"DevMenu"];
    }
  }

  // Add this line...
  __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

  // If you want to use the `JSCExecutorFactory`, remember to add the `#import <React/JSCExecutorFactory.h>`
  // import statement on top.
  return std::make_unique<facebook::react::HermesExecutorFactory>(
    facebook::react::RCTJSIExecutorRuntimeInstaller([weakSelf, bridge](facebook::jsi::Runtime &runtime) {
      if (!bridge) {
        return;
      }

      // And add these lines to install the bindings...
      __typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
      if (strongSelf) {
        facebook::react::RuntimeExecutor syncRuntimeExecutor =
            [&](std::function<void(facebook::jsi::Runtime & runtime_)> &&callback) { callback(runtime); };
        [strongSelf->_turboModuleManager installJSBindingWithRuntimeExecutor:syncRuntimeExecutor];
      }
    }));
}

#pragma mark RCTTurboModuleManagerDelegate

- (Class)getModuleClassFromName:(const char *)name
{
  return RCTCoreModulesClassProvider(name);
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const std::string &)name
                                                      jsInvoker:(std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::CallInvoker>)jsInvoker
{
  return nullptr;
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const std::string &)name
                                                     initParams:
                                                         (const facebook::react::ObjCTurboModule::InitParams &)params
{
  return nullptr;
}

- (id<RCTTurboModule>)getModuleInstanceFromClass:(Class)moduleClass
{
  // Set up the default RCTImageLoader and RCTNetworking modules.
  if (moduleClass == RCTImageLoader.class) {
    return [[moduleClass alloc] initWithRedirectDelegate:nil
        loadersProvider:^NSArray<id<RCTImageURLLoader>> *(RCTModuleRegistry * moduleRegistry) {
          return @ [[RCTLocalAssetImageLoader new]];
        }
        decodersProvider:^NSArray<id<RCTImageDataDecoder>> *(RCTModuleRegistry * moduleRegistry) {
          return @ [[RCTGIFImageDecoder new]];
        }];
  } else if (moduleClass == RCTNetworking.class) {
     return [[moduleClass alloc]
        initWithHandlersProvider:^NSArray<id<RCTURLRequestHandler>> *(
            RCTModuleRegistry *moduleRegistry) {
          return @[
            [RCTHTTPRequestHandler new],
            [RCTDataRequestHandler new],
            [RCTFileRequestHandler new],
          ];
        }];
  }
  // No custom initializer here.
  return [moduleClass new];
}

#endif

@end
```

When I try to run my project without enabling `TurboModules` and `Fabric`, it works fine for the first time

If I uncomment `RCTEnableTurboModule(YES);` in the above code I get an error saying

```
Unable to find module for RedBox
```

If I again comment `RCTEnableTurboModule(YES);` and try to just use `Fabric`,  I get  an error saying `No member named ‘’RCTJSIExecutorRuntimeInstaller’ in namespace ‘facebook::react’` Check this https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/artable-5da4b.appspot.com/o/Fabric%20Error.png?alt=media&token=9a3a3ce2-3e77-4236-bad8-bf9535ba1bdc for more details

For `Fabric` I did update my `podfile` to use `Fabric`. I did update `babel.config.js` as well

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    './node_modules/react-native/packages/babel-plugin-codegen',
  ],
};
```

and ran

```
USE_FABRIC=1 RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 pod install
```

Then I try to comment fabric as well along with TurboModules and reverted `babel.config.js` to original code. Did `pod install` and `npm I` as well but I get an error saying

```
React/renderer/components/view/ViewEventEmitter.h file not found
```

Check this https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/artable-5da4b.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202022-04-09%20at%206.29.17%20PM.png?alt=media&token=d76ace74-cf62-48a0-8663-4777ad0f505b

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was stuck with this problem the whole day, and finally figured it out.

I only had this issue when I reverted from using the new architecture, but still wanted to stay on 0.68. From reading https://reactnative.dev/docs/new-architecture-troubleshooting, I tried wiping the generated code (in `ios/build/generated`), then ran `pod install` and all was good.

Comment: This worked for me. I guess RN developers didn't account for that particular case!